# Get Object Value from array and pass to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm using ui.jQuery autocomplete.

I have the following array and I want to pass a specific object selected from an input box to a PHP function.

```
0: Object { nomeComune: "ROMA", provincia: "RM" }
​
1: Object { nomeComune: "ROMAGNANO AL MONTE", provincia: "SA" }
​
2: Object { nomeComune: "ROMAGNANO SESIA", provincia: "NO" }
​
3: Object { nomeComune: "ROMAGNESE", provincia: "PV" }
​
4: Object { nomeComune: "ROMANA", provincia: "SS" }
​
5: Object { nomeComune: "ROMANENGO", provincia: "CR" }
​
6: Object { nomeComune: "ROMANO CANAVESE", provincia: "TO" }
​
7: Object { nomeComune: "ROMANO D'EZZELINO", provincia: "VI" }
​
8: Object { nomeComune: "ROMANO DI LOMBARDIA", provincia: "BG" }
​
9: Object { nomeComune: "ROMANS D'ISONZO", provincia: "GO" }
​
10: Object { nomeComune: "ROMBIOLO", provincia: "VV" }
​
11: Object { nomeComune: "ROMENO", provincia: "TN" }
​
12: Object { nomeComune: "ROMENTINO", provincia: "NO" }
​
13: Object { nomeComune: "ROMETTA", provincia: "ME" }
```

the data of this array displays correctly on the autocomplete function. My problem is that I want to pass the object value selected to a php function.

I tried with this script without success:

```
select: function() {
                    var inputValue = $('#comuni :selected').text();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: ajaxUrl,
                        data: {
                            action: 'stato_comuni',
                            inputValue: inputValue
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(inputValue);

                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
                },
```

HTML:

```
<div class="input-group inputComuni">
                        <input name="search" id="comuni" class="form-control large-input align-middle" type="text" autocomplete=off placeholder="Inserisci il nome del tuo Comune"><i class="fas fa-search fa-lg"></i>
                    </div>
```

PHP:

```
function stato_comuni() {

    $term = $_POST['inputValue'];
    $request = wp_remote_get( "https://demo.ec2webdesign.com/anpr-dev/comuni.json", array(
            'headers'   => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json;')
        ));
        if( is_wp_error( $request ) ) {
            return false;
        }
        $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
        $jsonData = json_decode($body, false, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);

        assert(property_exists($jsonData, 'comuni'));
        assert(is_array($jsonData->comuni));

        $jsonFiltered = array_filter(
            $jsonData->comuni,
            static function ($item) use ($term) {
                assert(property_exists($item, 'nomeComune'));
                return $term === $item->nomeComune;
            }
        );

        // Back to JSON
        echo json_encode($jsonFiltered);

        wp_die();

}
```

My goal is to get the term selected and filter it inside a Json file. My filtering fuction works fine but I'm in trouble to get the correct value selected from the user.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The plugin that has the `select` callback probably exposes the specific object from the array as an argument in that function. Really not enough troubleshooting details given here to provide more specific help

Comment: For starters which specific plugin are you using ? There are several different autocomplete plugins around

Comment: I'm using ui.jQuery autocomplete.